# ng-click doesn't work with dynamic html

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I create dynamic html in html ng-click doesn't work..
My code is as follow

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
            function(results) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i] + " : " +i);
                     var tmpfileName = results[i].substr(results[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                     var fileName=i+"_"+tmpfileName

                     var image = document.getElementById('addArea');
                     var DOM_img = document.createElement("img");
                     DOM_img.setAttribute("id",fileName)
                     var cancel_img = document.createElement("img");
                     cancel_img.src="img/Action-cancel-icon.png";
                     cancel_img.setAttribute("id","cancel_"+fileName);
                     cancel_img.alt="no image";

                    cancel_img.setAttribute("ng-click","test()");
                    DOM_img.src=results[i];
                     DOM_img.height="100";
                     DOM_img.width="100";
                     image.appendChild(DOM_img);
                     image.appendChild(temp);
                     convertImgToBase64URL(results[i], function(base64Img){

                     $scope.images.push(base64Img);

                     console.log("Added... id  i " + i);


                    });

                }
})

$scope.test=function()
{
alert("hello")
}
```

I also tried following code

```
$scope.myHtml+="<img src='"+results[i]+"' height=100px width=100px ng-click='test()'>";
<div id="addArea" ng-bind-html="myHtml">
</div>
```

but ng-click not working

How can I solve this?

ng-click doesn't work on image..
I simply write test function when i click on image nothing happened..
How can I do this ?
please help me to solve this

Comment: You shoudn't create html inside controller. It's not the Angular way. It's better to create a directive for this purpose. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: could you also please let us know the test function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your element:

`$compile(cancel_img)($scope);`

Remember to inject `$compile` in your controller so you can use it:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

  // Your code and the $compile goes here

}]);
```

Comment: @user3855589 Have you injected it?

Comment: can you please suggest me how can i do this I add direcives compile but didn't work

Comment: @user3855589 I modified the answer with how to inject it

Answer (score 0):

dynamic html is a contradictory concept to the way angular works.

if all other (2 way binding) means fail and you really must inject html - I would use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 0):

For the reason, attribute of html when you use angularJs such as (ng-click, ng-show, ...) should be **enter in html code**, because when we run application, compiler will compile attribute such as "ng-click" to javascript before run app